# YouTube API "mostPopular" requests doesn't seem to give updated results

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It seems that the YouTube API doesn't give updated results for mostPopular videos in my country since few days.

Example:
This request (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&chart=mostpopular&regionCode=FR) doesn't give me the same videos results than the ones displayed directly on YouTube for the French most popular channel (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmzy72gDEpfXoFV9Xdtd0DQ). It seems that the results of this request is not updated since the 1th of february. Results was real time updated before this.

Does someone know if something is wrong with my API request, or if there are some issues with the YouTube API at this moment?

Comment: I am not getting results back from after February 01, 2016 regardless of regionCode and videoCategoryId being passed in.  All of the ones I've tried have this same problem.

@google You tell us explicitly to come here for help (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) - that your engineers monitor the very tags present on this issue, yet you have no response at all.  What gives, oh overlords of the internet?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your request.  This is a known issue with the YouTube API reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6676&q=label%3AAPi-YouTube%20mostPopular&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) for Saudi Arabia (but also applicable to multiple regions), and another related issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7192&q=label%3AAPi-YouTube%20mostPopular&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) with regard to content from France.

Your best bet would be to follow up with the YouTube team on one of those defects, or potentially (and dangerously) scrape the YouTube site for the correct results.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer !
I openned an issue and hope a google answer (https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7999)

Comment: I'd actually be very careful with bringing up issues like this with the YouTube developer team. At this point it is known that they are a bunch of monkeys behind typewriters.

There was an issue with inconsistent data retrieval with the Watch Later and Watch History playlists, they ended up removing the endpoint altogether rather than fix the issue - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be solved since 13th of february (maybe someone from Google have seen my post..)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Channels and `chart=mostPopular` parameter data are separate data entities, aka you will get different results. They may be related but there is no guarantee you will get the same data. To get the data that you want you may need to query for channel itself and its videos.

I got this information from [the thread](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6676#c1) @Jal linked, there was an update by matthewc...@google.com a few days ago:

> The [most popular channel for Saudia
>   Arabia](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWY-_j1MCth6yf24m58Bh_Q) and
>   the `mostPopular` chart parameter in [the `video.list`
>   call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart)
>   are separate and distinct entities.  If you'd like to get the content
>   of the [most popular channel for Saudia
>   Arabia](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWY-_j1MCth6yf24m58Bh_Q)
>   please use the Data API `video.list` call to list the videos with the
>   channel ID (in this case "`UCWY-_j1MCth6yf24m58Bh_Q`") by setting the
>   `items/snippet/channelId` parameter.

My current concern right now is that there is supposedly a way to get video information from the `videos.list` endpoint using a `channelId`, which does not seem the case in the API Explorer. I will update my answer once I figure out what this person meant exactly.